# Access form field object in Template

Tags: playframework-2.2

In playframework-2.2 I have a custom form with a `List<Long> selected`

In the template, how can I access this List for iteration?

`form("selected").value` gives me the string representation

however

`form("selected[0]").value` gives me the value at posistion 0.

Comment: Have you tried asInstanceOf[List] ?

Comment: I've tried form("selected").asInstanceOf[List[Long]] and got this error [[ClassCastException: play.data.Form$Field cannot be cast to java.util.List]]

Comment: I had meant after .value, btw, take a look at my answer below

Comment: After .value I also get ClassCastException: [ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use @repeat helper.
E.g provided by play docs

```
@repeat(myForm("emails"), min = 1) { emailField =>

    @inputText(emailField)

}
```

[See more](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers)

Comment: And how can I iterate if I have a Map<Long, Boolean>?